# ColorPicker opens in background

Tags: java, vaadin

i have a problem with ColorPicker. The first time i click on the Button, the ColorPicker opens in background. I cannot click it and it is grayed out. Only the second time the Popup is in front and accessable.

```
component = new ColorPicker(caption, hex2Rgb(settings.get(constant)));
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
gridLayout.addComponent(component);
valuePanel.setContentLayout(gridLayout);
```

Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you make the component null before you call it with a method
you can try this

```
if (component = null) {
    component = new ColorPicker(caption, hex2Rgb(settings.get(constant)));
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.addComponent(component);
    valuePanel.setContentLayout(gridLayout);
    component.setVisible(true);
    component.requestFocus();
} else {
    component.setVisible(true);
    component.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: Component does not have the method grabFocus()?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it to requestFocus. If this doesn't work, you might need to create a method which makes the component to be the focus owner and then call that method instead.